# ansible copy config file on each host

Tags: linux, ansible, administration

I have a 2 VM's with hostnames

```
bishkek-01
bishkek-02
```

and and i have 2 config files which named

```
bishkek-01.cfg
bishkek-02.cfg
```

and how to copy for example bishkek-01.cfg to bishkek-01 and bishkek-02.cfg to bishkek-02 vm? using group vars

Answer (score 3):

you can use copy module like this

```
- name: Copying the config file to remote machine
    copy: 
      src: {{ inventory_hostname }}.cfg 
      dest: <Your destination goes here>
```

Comment: @uralsk Great to hear that. You can accept this answer.. ;)